# Why is $\operatorname{Fun}(A^{*},\mathbb C^{*})$ injective?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, injective-module

Everything below is a $\mathbb Z-$mod.

Let $A^{*}$ = $(\operatorname{Hom}A,\mathbb C^{*})$.
I(A) = $\operatorname{Fun}(A^{*},\mathbb C^{*})$. [note :  only functions,not homomorphisms]

> Why is I(A) an injective module?

I know that $\mathbb C^{*}$ is injective (as it is divisible).

Comment: $I(A)$ is also divisible, since $\mathbf C^*$ is.

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: After checking again,I got it.

Comment: If D is divisible, so is Fun(M,D). Given any f in Fun(M,D) and n in Z, we want n.g=f which is possible pointwise.

Comment: That's correct.